# How best to include a one-off script in your Loopback 4 app?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm confused how to run a one-off script as part of a Loopback 4 project that fills in a value for old records. E.g. I want to include a createdAt field on the user record and fill in old records based on the timestamp of the first post each user made in the system.

I've tried creating a component that will run one time only to update all these records.

```
export class OneTimeComponent implements Component {
    constructor(
      @repository(UserRepository)
      public userRepository : UserRepository,
    ){
      this.start()
    }

    async start(){
      const users = await this.userRepository.find();

      users.forEach( user => {
        // find first post for user
        // get date 
        // update user.createdAt with date
      })
    }

}

export async function run(args: string[]) {
  const app = new BlogApiApplication();

  app.component(OneTimeComponent);

  await app.boot();

  // Connectors usually keep a pool of opened connections,
  // this keeps the process running even after all work is done.
  // We need to exit explicitly.
  process.exit(0);
}

run(process.argv).catch(err => {
  console.error('Cannot run this', err);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

If I run `app.start()` then the script will try to run by booting up the app and then I get an error saying this address is in use – obviously because there are 2 apps running.

And I'd call this file with package script.

To access the repositories does this need to be a boot script? Or something else?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> How to run a one-off script as part of a Loopback 4 project that fills in a value for old records. E.g. I want to include a createdAt field on the user record and fill in old records based on the timestamp of the first post each user made in the system.

Personally, I would make these change as part of database-schema migration, see [Database Migrations](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Database-migrations.html) in LoopBack documentation.

Most LoopBack connectors are smart enough to add `createdAt` field to your `User` table if it's not present yet. Filling the values is left for you to implement.

Quoting from [Implement additional migration steps](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Database-migrations.html#implement-additional-migration-steps):

> In some scenarios, the application may need to define additional schema constraints or seed the database with predefined model instances. This can be achieved by overriding the `migrateSchema` method provided by the mixin.
>
> The example below shows how to do so in our Todo example application.

```js
/** FILE: src/application.ts **/
import {TodoRepository} from './repositories';
// skipped: other imports

export class TodoListApplication extends BootMixin(
  ServiceMixin(RepositoryMixin(RestApplication)),
) {
  // skipped: the constructor, etc.

  async migrateSchema(options?: SchemaMigrationOptions) {
    // 1. Run migration scripts provided by connectors
    await super.migrateSchema(options);

    // 2. Make further changes. When creating predefined model instances,
    // handle the case when these instances already exist.
    const todoRepo = await this.getRepository(TodoRepository);
    const found = await todoRepo.findOne({where: {title: 'welcome'}});
    if (found) {
      todoRepo.updateById(found.id, {isComplete: false});
    } else {
      await todoRepo.create({title: 'welcome', isComplete: false});
    }
  }
}
```

> I've tried creating a component that will run one time only to update all these records.
>   (...)
>   To access the repositories does this need to be a boot script? Or something else?

If you don't want to migrate the database schema & data explicitly by running `npm run migrate`, you can modify your Application to call `autoMigrate` automatically as part of the exported `main` function.

Quoting from [Auto-update database at start](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Database-migrations.html#auto-update-database-at-start):

> To automatically update the database schema whenever the application is started, modify your main script to execute `app.migrateSchema()` after the application was bootstrapped (all repositories were registered) but before it is actually started.

```js
/** FILE: src/index.ts **/

export async function main(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {
  const app = new TodoListApplication(options);
  await app.boot();
  await app.migrateSchema();
  await app.start();

  const url = app.restServer.url;
  console.log(`Server is running at ${url}`);

  return app;
}
```

The last option is to leverage life-cycle observers (a.k.a "boot scripts" in LoopBack v3) - see [Life cycle events](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Life-cycle.html):

1. Scaffold a new observer by running `lb4 observer` (see [Life cycle observer generator](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Life-cycle-observer-generator.html)).
2. Modify the constructor of the observer class to inject model repositories you want to work with.
3. Modify the `start` method to perform the required database changes.